# Correct way of databinding to DateTime.Now.DayOfWeek?

Tags: c#, wpf, datetime, mvvm, data-binding

I would like to bind the DateTime.Now.DayOfWeek property. This will be shown in the view through databinding.

It's no problem to bind the DayOfWeek property, but..... How Can I detect the end of the day without using a timer to check it continuously (for example every hour..)?

Comment: You can use asynchronous programming and use `Task.Delay`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't. Simple as that.

Use timers.